# How to merge overlapping objects for UV?

Tags: uv, baking

I want to make the UV for the walls as big as possible for when it comes time to bake. The ridges were a separate object I joined with the walls. I tried using boolean to chop up the walls but it didn't really work. How do I get the ridges into the walls?

[image]

[image]